# Goodman AH2429-1A

Tags: electrical, hvac, thermostat

I am trying to convert my old thermostat to a Wyze smart one and everything was going smoothly until I tried to connect the c wire adapter. I can’t find the terminals labeled YRGW like it wants me to. Everyone else’s that I looked at, looks different and more like a control panel instead of so many wires every which way. Am I looking in the wrong spot? Or how would I connect the c wire adapter to this setup? Thanks!

It won’t let me add the photos because it says they’re too large, so here’s a link to the photos https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1j-b3DRG-Xc6a8XSoeqwKp-wbExQ0KDgF

Answer (score 1):

### You're after the light blue wires

According to the wiring diagram and photo posted, the light blue wires in your setup are the C wires.  You may need to use a "piggyback" tab crimp terminal to access them if there's not a free end or wirenut junction you can splice to, though.